# How to ssh to EC2 *without* having to specify the .pem file?

Tags: linux, ssh, openssh, amazon-ec2, ssh-keys

There must be some easier way than the documented `ssh -i my.pem user@ip-addr`, by putting the pem file in `~/.ssh` and ssh knowing to use `my.pem` based on `user@ip-addr`, but I can't figure out how.

Answer (score 10):

This solution comes from the StackOverflow post
[Connect to Amazon ec2 Instance without specifying .pem file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33815711/connect-to-amazon-ec2-instance-without-specifying-pem-file):

> - Copy the `.pem` file to `~/.ssh`
> - Create a config file at `~/.ssh`
>
>   ```
>   touch ~/.ssh/config
>   ```
> - open the config file in nano or vim: `nano ~/.ssh/config`
> - Add the following line to `config` file
>
>   ```
>   Host host_name
>       HostName ec2.server.address.com
>       User ec2-user
>       IdentityFile "~/.ssh/ec2.pem"
>   ```
> - Now connect from terminal: `ssh host_name`.

Answer (score 6):

Most command-line options can be specified through `~/.ssh/config`, either globally or for individual hosts. The equivalent of `-i` is the `IdentityFile` option.

If this key file is *only* used for EC2, it's best to specify this in a section that only matches EC2. For example, if you usually SSH by name (e.g. `ssh ec2-198-x.compute-1.amazonaws.com`), this format would work:

```
Host *.amazonaws.com
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/myec2.pem
```

(The most-specific sections should go at the top; the global `Host *` section should go at the very bottom of the file.)

---

In addition to this, OpenSSH will also look at several fixed locations, such as `~/.ssh/id_rsa`, for the private key file. You could place the key there, but it's better to reserve this filename for your "main" key, and one that you generated yourself and not just received from AWS.